# this and passing function as parameter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I have following Javascript objects:

```
function Alfa() {
  this.status='';
  this.setStatus = function(value) {
    this.status=value
  }
}

function Beta() {
  this.setSomething = function(setter) {
    setter('Something');
  }
}
```

And than execution:

```
alf=new Alfa();
alf.setStatus('foo');
```

This works fine, if you look into values of *alf*, the *status* is set to 'foo', but:

```
bet=new Beta();
bet.setSomething(a.setStatus);
```

What I have expected is that *bet* will execute *setStatus* function of *alf* and set *status* value to 'something', however, this is not happening. 
*setStatus* of *alf* is executed, but this points not to *alf* instance but to *Window*, so the property status is set for *Window* not for *alf*.

What is the proper approach to get desired functionality?

This is of course simplified implementation, in real life i want to pass those functions of *alf* to event handlers, so I cannot change *Beta* implementation, eg:

```
$('xxx').click(alf.setStatus)
```

Comment: I can at least one error: you pass a.setStatus to bet.setSomething() but where is a declared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript functions are unbound. That means `this` is determined by how it's invoked rather than how it was defined. Because you are invoking the method from within `bet`, then `this` is `bet`

To get around this you need to make a *bound function*, which creates a stable `this` no matter how the function is invoked.

If you are using an ES5 compatible JavaScript interpreter then you can use: [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
alf.setStatus.bind(alf)
```

Or if you arent there are several es5 shims that provide this functionality in older interpreters. In fact one is provided on the mdn reference for bind. JQuery has a version called `$.proxy`

A simple implementation is that you want a function that takes a function and a scope. And then calls your method in that scope specifically, rather than using this. Something like.

```
function bind(func,o) { return function() { func.call(o); } }
```

Comment: the correct would be `alf.setStatus.bind(alf)`, as the syntax is `fn.bind(context)`

Comment: Yes sorry. I'm on the train and trying to type this on my phone. Auto correct also got my a few times. Making an edit.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `$.proxy`, as I usually use underscore.js `_.bind()`

Answer (score 1):

Functions in JavaScript don't have a context attached to them, like e.g. bound methods in Python. So what you can do is to call setStatus functions with a context, like this:

```
bet.setSomething(function(value) {
    a.setStatus.call(a, value);
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: "so I cannot change Beta implementation"

Comment: And additionally this reduces the functionality of Beta objects (as it has to know that there is method setStatus of alfa objects)
So not the best idea

Answer (score 1):

Change `setter('Something');` to `setter.call(this, 'Something');` will be work.

Comment: "so I cannot change Beta implementation"

Answer (score 1):

```
function Alfa() {
    this.status='';
    this.setStatus = function(value) {
        this.status=value
    }
}
function Beta() {
    this.status='';
    this.setSomething = function(setter) {
        setter.call(this,'Something');
     }
}
```